# SQL Select - Flag if the value appears in another table

Tags: sql, select, case

Update: Does anyone know how to do it in Pyspark?

Trying to work through a SPARK SQL query. I have two tables, and need to create a column to flag if the value in a.id appears in b.id. There's always syntax error on the line < CASE WHEN a.ID IN (SELECT b.ID FROM b) THEN 'appear' >, mentioning 'mismatched input 'a', should expecting EOF, ';'  '. I could not use 'JOIN' since the a.id have multiple appearance in b.id, and the table got messed up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUTsp.png)
Table a:

[ID][Description]

112   MM

121   NN

123   DD

Table b:

[ID][Action]

112     A

112     B

112     C

131     A

```
 SELECT a.ID,

 CASE WHEN a.ID IN (SELECT b.ID FROM b) THEN 'appear' 

        ELSE 'no'

        END AS Flag 

FROM a
```

Comment: The syntax looks okay to me.

Comment: Your code looks fine. Recommend you tag your database and maybe create a DB Fiddle that demonstrates your specific problem.

Comment: Since you added a screenshot of the data, maybe add a screenshot of your actual query?  Maybe you're fixing something when you retype this that you're missing.

Comment: I was doing this under Spark SQL. Do you think that's the reason it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It's a little less heavy.

```
SELECT  a.ID
        ,ISNULL((
                    SELECT  'appear'
                    FROM    b
                    WHERE   a.ID = b.ID
                ), 'no'
               ) AS Flag
FROM    a;
```

Here's another way to answer the same question using OUTER APPLY.

```
SELECT  a.ID
        ,CASE
             WHEN hc.HitCount > 0 THEN 'appear'
             ELSE 'no'
         END AS Flag
FROM    a
        OUTER APPLY (
                        SELECT  COUNT(1) AS HitCount
                        FROM    b
                        WHERE   a.ID = b.ID
                    ) AS hc;
```